# I need help to setup DNS entries for exchange server

Tags: dns, exchange

My infrastructure setup is like below:

I have a IP pool from my ISP (containing 5 real IP and I want to use one for mail server)
My AD integrated zone is **abc.xyz.co.in** and my company name is **xyz.co.in** 
I have another DNS server which is connected to my LAN but not domain joined and where I can create DNS record to be reachable from outside.
My internet is connected via a firewall and NAT is there.
Kindly guide me what are the records I should ask to my ISP for entering to their DNS server and what are the DNS record I need to put into my external DNS as well as in my AD integrated DNS.

Comment: Shouldn't be as simple as creating an MX record through your domain registrar to point to your Exchange public IP address? You'll need to have an SMTP service somewhere, too, so that your Exchange server can send mails outbound... your ISP may have further advice on how you can use their SMTP.

Answer (score -1):

MX record for mailflow, and A records for client access. Such as Autodiscover.xyz.co.in(required) and mail.xyz.co.in(or other name like *.xyz.co.in). All you need to do is to make sure these Public Service Name will finally resolved to your internal Exchange server.

For your reference:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/37c84133-3766-4f83-a4d8-277eab49cf9b/dns-requirements-in-exchange-2013-which-rrs-to-create-what-do-they-do?forum=exchangesvrdeploy

Comment: I have MX record and mail server host record in my ISP's DNS server but when I'm sending mails my WAN IP is reflecting as sender mail server IP but my public IP for my mail server is different so my mails are getting blocked by some organization.

Comment: Have you set SPF record?